# TFS 2015 build agent

Tags: tfs-2015, build-agent

We have a build server running the new TFS 2015 build agent in an agent pool. I have looked and cannot find a way to 'increase' the number of consecutive builds to run.

Basically, I would like to have our build server be able to build two different requests at the same time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are using different agent pools, you can [set up multiple TFS Build Agents](https://binary-stuff.com/post/setting-up-tfs-build-agents-fast) on one build server (machine). If you are putting the agents in the same agent pool, your demand is not possible. There is a clear picture show in [how are agent pools and queues organized](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/admin/index)?

[image]

From the above picture you can see unless they are in a different agent pool, there is no possibility to build two different requests at the same time.

Moreover, there is also a parallel build in the vNext build definition. However, this parallel build **only has support for different platforms by different build variables**.

Comment: while I accept this is Microsoft's official answer, someone on the MSDN Forums has pointed out a 'workaround' of sorts by having multiple agents on a single build server.  This is not ideal but does accomplish the goal and acceptable for now.

Comment: Agreed. But for one thing. Why you want to edit my answer "can" to "can't " . Actually, you can hold multiple agents on a single build server for vNext. However, you can not run those agent in one agent pool  at the same time. That's why when you queue a build, you will get a prompt : " x position in queue." If you are using the different definition, such as a build and a release and not using a same queue agent. Then the requests can run in a totally parallel.

Comment: I misread your post and thought you had mistyped.  You may disregard my edit suggestions then.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness explanation.